# Using attribute routing and a global route for the same controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, attributerouting

So, we're developing a webapi-heavy application that serves multiple types of clients (including a website that's a JavaScript client and multiple C# clients), and we'd like to use attribute routing to make friendlier urls. Something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix(Constants.RoutePrefixes.Api + "foo")]
[HttpPut]
FooController : ApiController
{
     [Route("{fooId}/sub/{subFooId}")]
     [HttpPut]
     public HttpResponseMessage UpdateAFoo(int fooId, int subFooId)
     {
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
     }
}
```

And a request to /api/foo/1/sub/2 would hit this controller, as expected.

However, we have a message handler built into one of our default routes for processing identity tokens, and requests coming from clients that require that special behavior still have to use *that* route, or at least something that runs the appropriate message handler, and the following request (which uses that other route):

/integration/foo?fooId=1&subFooId=2

..gives me an error that no suitable controller could be found to handle the request. If I remove the route attribute, this second request hits my action method as expected.

I've read in several places that you can use both default and attribute routes, and I have both working in the application, but I haven't been able to use both for a specific action.

My route config looks like this:

```
public static void RegisterHttpRoutes(HttpConfiguration configuration)
{
        var routes = configuration.Routes;

        configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: Constants.RouteNames.Api,
            routeTemplate: Constants.RoutePrefixes.Api + "{controller}/{id}/{p}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, p = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: Constants.RouteNames.IntegrationApi,
            routeTemplate: Constants.RoutePrefixes.IntegrationApi + "{controller}/{id}/{p}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, p = RouteParameter.Optional },
            constraints: null,
            handler: new SuperDuperAuthenticationHandler())
        );
    }
```

Is that just how it works? Do I need a separate action without the route attribute? Is there a way to specify message handlers for attribute routes? Can I have both attribute and convention routing apply to the same action method? I'm not really clear on what my options are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controllers/Actions which are decorated with attribute routes cannot be reached via routes matched by conventional routing...so the behavior that you are seeing is expected...

Per-route message handlers are not supported for attribute routes.

Can you use `AuthenticationFilterAttribute` for your scenario?...if you need this filter for a set of controllers, then you could probably create a base controller decorated with this filter and let all these set of controller derive from it...

Comment: Unfortunately, I need it for all controllers/actions, but only for certain clients - which, so far, I've solved by using different routes to the same controllers. I'll either duplicate the action methods (which are thin wrappers around a service implementation anyway) or ditch attribute routing. Either way, I think I have my answer.

Thanks!